# what is the difference between entity and dynamicEntitiy?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to know when should I use DynamicEntity and what are the differences 
between DynamicEntity and an Entity?
what are the advantages of using DynamicEntity  ?

Answer (score 3):

`DynamicEntity` was a CRM 4.0 concept (together with `BusinessEntity`).

CRM 2011 programming model introduced the `Entity` concept, so `DynamicEntity` (and `BusinessEntity`) is no longer used.

Inside Dynamics CRM `Entity` holds a record of a specific entity (for example Account)

```
Entity companyA = service.Retrieve("account", accountId, new ColumnSet(true));
```